# JavaScript Refactor From Two to Many Function Arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

These two JavaScript functions each accept TWO array arguments and return ONE array result. Conforming to ES3, how can I rewrite these to accept an indefinite number of array inputs?

```
function sum(v, w) {
    for (var a = jsArray(v), b = jsArray(w), t = 0; t < a.length; t++) a[t] += b[t];
    return vbArray(a);
}

function mul(v, w) {
    for (var a = jsArray(v), b = jsArray(w), t = 0; t < a.length; t++) a[t] *= b[t];
    return vbArray(a);
}
```

---

The odd `jsArray()` function is required because the arrays to be processed are coming from VBA and jsArray() converts them to JavaScript arrays:

```
function jsArray(v) {
    return new VBArray(v).toArray()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use array-like object [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in order to get all passed arguments:

```js
function someFunc() {
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}

someFunc('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Example of transformed `sum` function. Beware that this works if all the passed arrays have the same length.

```js
function sum() {
  var arrays = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arrays[i] = jsArray(arguments[i]);
  }
  
  for (var j = 1; j < arrays.length; j++) {
    for (var t = 0; t < arrays[0].length; t++) {
       arrays[0][t] += arrays[j][t];
    }
  }
  
  return vbArray(arrays[0]);
}
```

Generalized solution:

```js
function process(concreteFunc) {
  var arrays = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    arrays.push(jsArray(arguments[i]));
  }

  for (var j = 1; j < arrays.length; j++) {
    for (var t = 0; t < arrays[0].length; t++) {
       arrays[0][t] = concreteFunc(arrays[0][t], arrays[j][t]);
    }
  }

  return vbArray(arrays[0]);
}

var sum = process.bind(null, function (a, b) {return a + b});
var mul = process.bind(null, function (a, b) {return a * b});
```

Solution without `.bind`:

```js
function process(concreteFunc, args) {
  var arrays = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    arrays.push(jsArray(args[i]));
  }

  for (var j = 1; j < arrays.length; j++) {
    for (var t = 0; t < arrays[0].length; t++) {
       arrays[0][t] = concreteFunc(arrays[0][t], arrays[j][t]);
    }
  }

  return vbArray(arrays[0]);
}

function createFunc(handler) {
  return function() {
    return process(handler, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  }
}

var sum = createFunc(function (a, b) {return a + b});
var mul = createFunc(function (a, b) {return a * b});
```

Improved version to support ability to implement `avg`:

```js
function process(concreteFunc, args) {
  var arrays = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    arrays.push(jsArray(args[i]));
  }

  var result = [];
  
  for (var j = 0; j < arrays[0].length; j++) {
    var items = [];
    
    for (var t = 0; t < arrays.length; t++) {
      items.push(arrays[t][j]);
    }
    
    result.push(concreteFunc(items));
  }

  return vbArray(result);
}

function createFunc(handler) {
  return function() {
    return process(handler, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  }
}

function reduce(items, handler) {
  var result = items[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
    result = handler(result, items[i]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

var sum = createFunc(function(items) {
  return reduce(items, function (a, b) {return a + b});
});
var mul = createFunc(function(items) {
  return reduce(items, function (a, b) {return a * b});
});
var avg = createFunc(function(items) {
  return reduce(items, function (a, b) {return a + b}) / items.length;
});
```

Comment: OK, but could you please integrate that pattern into my `sum()` function?

Comment: @ExcelHero added the example for your `sum` function. you can transform your `mul` function the same way.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks! I am marking your answer as accepted. But can you also show me how to make the function generic? For example, can I have one core function that can do many different operations... sum, mul, avg, etc?

Comment: @ExcelHero added another example with a generalized solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote your answer another time if I could.

Comment: I'm getting an error. Is `.bind()` supported in ES3?

Comment: The error is: Object does not support this property or method. The error happens on the following line: `var sum = process.bind...`

Comment: I researched and discovered that `bind()` is not supported in ES3. I tried a bind polyfill and it still errors. Can you rework the generalized solution without using `bind`?

Comment: @ExcelHero added solution without `.bind`

Comment: Your solution without `.bind` works perfectly. Thank you. If I make a new question, do you have time to answer it? This setup will work fine for the basic ops, but I'm trying to wrap my head around how to alter this to work for averaging the arrays.

Comment: For example: `var avg = `

Comment: I tried:  `var avg = createFunc(sum() / arguments.length);` but it errors with: 'length' is null or not an object.

Comment: @ExcelHero changed the solution to support `avg` function.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you! It seems that even with the new solution, I can still use the older and shorter definitions for the basic ops like:  `var sum = createFunc(function (a, b) {return a + b});`